# How to translate WCF service security bindings to WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm working on converting an existing WCF web service to a WebAPI service.  But I am new to WebAPI and am confused as to how to implement the same security that is declared in the WCF security bindings in WebAPI.

In the WCF web service the security bindings for the service are defined in the web.config file.  In researching how to implement similar security in WebAPI, I came across some articles which appear to use the WCF model, such as [Wcf WebApi configuration equivalent to code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819705/wcf-webapi-configuration-equivalent-to-code).  But that appears to be deprecated functionality which was not part of the final release.  The classes and methods do not exist (that I can find) in the current version.

Most of the other articles/books I've looked at do not mention any explicit, configurable security bindings - instead relying on the host configuration, message handlers, authentication attributes, or action filters to handle authentication and authorization security checking.  (Ex:  [1](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api), [2](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449337711/ch_security.html), [3](http://www.piotrwalat.net/client-certificate-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-windows-store-apps/))

I'm comfortable implementing the security relying on the host, message handlers, etc. but don't know if I'm completely missing something.  I don't want to be hacking in security as part of message handling, etc. if there is a better way to set it up via configuration or some other way.

Should I be relying on the host, message handlers, authentication attributes, etc. for implementing security in WebAPI, or is there a more appropriate way to do it?  And if so, how?